# ASP.NET Core MVC - Override Layout on ALL Identity Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-layout

I have a **_ViewStart.cshtml** file in **Identity** > **Pages**. The contents of this file looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}
```

When I navigate to the **Account** > **Manage** > **Index** view, the Layout value defaults to:

```
/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml
```

I override it like this on the Index page itself:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Everything works fine now!

I don't want to have to do this on every page within the Identity area. I thought **_ViewStart.cshtml** was meant to apply what I set here to all pages in the Identity area. Isn't working that way...

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

I also created a **_Layout** page in the Manage folder and set the Layout like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}
@RenderBody()
```

Didn't help, I get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The layout page '/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml' cannot find the section 'SectionTitle1' in the content page '/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Index.cshtml'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought _ViewStart.cshtml was meant to apply what I set here to all
> pages in the Identity area. Isn't working that way...

_ViewStart.cshtml is used to set the default view layout in ASP.NET Core MVC. It can specify a default layout page for all views in a specific directory.

> I don't want to have to do this on every page within the Identity
> area.

If you want to view your _LoginLayout on all identity pages, you can modify the default layout configuration by selecting your layout in identity scaffold.. identity is a framework that handles authentication and authorization. The identity framework contains a set of automatically generated pages which provides default layout pages for user authentication and authorization. This layout page is typically located in `Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml`. you can  change the layout to your `_LoginLayout` .Here is an example you can use as a reference:

I create a LoginLayout page under this path :`/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml`:
[image]

I changed the _viewstart configuration in identity:

[image]

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Since I need to change the layout page in identity, Select the layout page in identity scaffold.
[image]

Then I  change the default configuration to `_LoginLayout.cshtml`

```
@{
    if (ViewData.TryGetValue("ParentLayout", out var parentLayout) && parentLayout !=  null)
    {
        Layout = parentLayout.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
    }
}

<h1>Manage your account</h1>

<div>
    <h2>Change your account settings</h2>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <partial name="_ManageNav" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

Finally start accessing the page  in  identity

[image]